# Ionic 5 login api doesn't work, used to work in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

Hello i am trying to migrate from ionic 3 to ionic 5. My login function works fine in Ionic 3 but i am getting error on Ionic 5. Php function works fine i 've checked it. The thing is that it does not get inside if(data.success). loginData credentials are shown ok in console.log

```
  login() {
    this.userData.login(this.loginData).pipe(
        map((data:any) => {
         console.log(this.loginData)//this.loginData is ok
          if (data.success) {
           console.log('data is sent');//this is NOT shown on console
          }
          else {
            alert('data is not sent');//this is shown on console
            }
          })
        ).subscribe()
      }
```

userdata.login function

```
   this.options = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 });

login(login_data) {
    const url = this.appData.getApiUrl() + 'login';
    const data = this.jsonToURLEncoded({
        login_data: login_data,
        app_version: this.appData.APP_VERSION
    });
    console.log('here');//this shows
    return this.http.post(url, data, this.options);
    console.log('here2')//unreachable code
```

jsonToURLEncoded function

```
 jsonToURLEncoded(obj) { // this is ok, you need to still add some code in the api, but for apple is just to be available in the app ok got what this does is send a notificaion on phone to say what you want to say api wise like simon created a new media? correctok so
var query = '', name, value, fullSubName, subName, subValue, innerObj, i;
for (name in obj) {
  value = obj[name];

  if (value instanceof Array) {
    for (i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
      subValue = value[i];
      fullSubName = name + '[' + i + ']';
      innerObj = {};
      innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
      query += this.jsonToURLEncoded(innerObj) + '&';
    }
  }
  else if (value instanceof Object) {
    for (subName in value) {
      subValue = value[subName];
      fullSubName = name + '[' + subName + ']';
      innerObj = {};
      innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
      query += this.jsonToURLEncoded(innerObj) + '&';
    }
  }
  else if (value !== undefined && value !== null)
    query += encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '&';
}//api is one on server phph slim is

return query.length ? query.substr(0, query.length - 1) : query;
}
```

i think the problem is with this.options any help?

Comment: What is supposed to be the code from `userData.login` method? Can you share it?

Comment: i have edited to show you KingDarBoja

Comment: i have updated again code is unreachable after 
    return this.http.post(url, data, this.options);

Comment: Any code being after a return statement will never be executed. Also, not sure why but you should pass the options inside the method instead of relying on some class-scoped variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare headers

from

```
return this.http.post(url, data, this.options);
```

to

```
 return this.http.post(url, data, {headers: this.options});
```

Comment: So you figured out the issue, glad to know :D

Comment: Yes that was it!